# Uploading a resume after filling out the cover letter deletes the cover letter

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, user-interface

I went to the "Apply" dialog and wrote a few paragraphs in response to a job listing. When I then attached a PDF resume, the dialog irretrievably discarded everything I had written.

Comment: Fixing this right now, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report and sorry for the inconvenience. This is now fixed and pushed to production.